# Django: cannot import name resolve_url

Tags: django, url, import, resolve

I was doing [2nd part of django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial02/) when i got this error after going to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/`:

```
ImportError at /admin/

cannot import name resolve_url

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version:     1.7.1
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

cannot import name resolve_url

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py in <module>, line 8
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.6
Python Path:    

['/home/xxx/Projects/mysite',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']

Server time:    Fri, 2 Jan 2015 22:44:47 +0000
```

I work on:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
```

Any idea how it fix?

Comment: Where do you use resolve_url?

Comment: @avenet "Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py in <module>, line 8
"  ;)

Comment: This is a pretty fundamental problem - since you're only on page 2 of the tutorial and haven't even entered any code yet, it should work "out of the box".   Can you confirm that everything on page 1 of the tutorial works for you?  I can see that your Django and Python versions are OK, so I think you might need to go to the django mailing list or IRC group and ask for help debugging your installation.  It's not a code problem of the sort that can usually be solved here.  Maybe start with a complete reinstall...

Comment: I installed django on the other OS, and this project work correctly, I mean I don't get this error. So thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not your mistake , it happened because of improper installation of Django.
My solution is go to the location where django folder is situated.
which is basically

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

From there remove the folder.

> sudo rm -rf django

Reinstall Django

> sudo pip install Django==1.7

or any version which u want.

Enjoy !!!

Comment: i have this problem too; and it dos'nt fix with these solutions